# No route in the route table matches the supplied values Error in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a below route setting, and when I want to use `return RedirectToAction("action", "controller");` then it causes error **No route in the route table matches the supplied values**.

How do I can fix this error?

Example Url:  localhost:16348/product/tv/42/10646

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {          
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{filter1}/{filter2}/{filter3}/{filter4}/{filter5}/{filter6}/{filter7}/{filter8}/{filter9}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "controllerA", action = "actionA",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                filter1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                filter2 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                filter3 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                filter4 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                filter5 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                filter6 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                filter7 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                filter8 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                filter9 = UrlParameter.Optional,
            }
        );
    }
```

main url is something like : localhost:16348/product/tv/42/10646/32/re/23 and in this issue I want to redirect to admin controller after user login

Comment: What URL was generated?

Comment: @ErikPhilips main url is somthing like : http://localhost:16348/product/tv/42/10646/ and in this issue I want to redirect to admin controller after login

Comment: Don't add question information in a comment, edit your answer.  This way people do not have to read every comment to answer your question.

Comment: How does your admin-Controller look like ( Attributes, BaseClass)?